# Shared pointers of a struct to use instances of handlers accross all files

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, shared-ptr

I'm trying to make a game, but I'm having some difficulties in trying to use the same instance of other classes across the other "handlers" (InputManager, Logger, AssetsManager, etc). These are the errors:

> - AssetManager.h(14,35): error C2061:  syntax error: identifier 'LogDataRef'
> - AssetManager.h(30,21): error C3646:  'logdata': unknown override specifier
> - AssetManager.h(30,21): error C4430:  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

This is my main game header where I instantiate all of the different handler classes

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "DEFINITIONS.h"

#include "AssetManager.h"
#include "StateMachine.h"
#include "LogSystem.h"
#include "FileParser.h"



namespace ME2D
{

    struct GameData {
        StateMachine machine;
        sf::RenderWindow window;
    };

    struct AssetData {
        AssetManager assetmanager;
    };

    struct LogData {
        LogSystem logger;
    };

    struct ParseData {
        FileParser parser;
    };

    typedef std::shared_ptr<GameData> GameDataRef;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<AssetData> AssetDataRef;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<LogData> LogDataRef;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<ParseData> ParseDataRef;

    class TDGame
    {
    public:
        TDGame();
    private:
        void Run();
    private:
        GameDataRef data = std::make_shared<GameData>();
        AssetDataRef assetdata = std::make_shared<AssetData>();
        LogDataRef logdata = std::make_shared<LogData>();
        ParseDataRef parsedata = std::make_shared<ParseData>();

        sf::Clock clock;

        const float dt = 1 / 60.f;
    };
}
```

This is the header file for the AssetManager class. Just deleted the functions in public to save on space (just basic loaders and getters).

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML/Audio.hpp"
#include "Block.h"
#include "2DGame.h"

namespace ME2D
{
    class AssetManager
    {
    public:
        // some functions here
    private:
        LogDataRef logdata;

        std::map<std::string, sf::Texture> mTextures;
        std::map<std::string, sf::Sprite> mSprites;
        std::map<std::string, sf::SoundBuffer> mSBuffers;
        std::map<std::string, sf::Sound> mSounds;
        std::map<std::string, ME2D::Block> mBlocks;
    };
}
```

I need to use the instances in the main game header across the other handlers. For this example, I need to use the instantiated log class that is in the game header inside the AssetsManager class (of course I need to use it in other handlers as well, so it writes all of the logged info in one file instead of creating multiple instances of the logger inside every handler and making multiple log files).

Also worth noting is that I've got no actual idea about how shared_ptr or make_shared works or what they do exactly, watched a dude make a state machine from a youtube video (cause I've got no idea how to, also stack and those things were present in the way of making a state machine, which I was probably able to grasp to some degree) and some info on those would also be very appreciated. Basically I'm a beginner, been coding for 3 months max, who is trying to make their first game and learning in the process.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the edit!

Comment: AssetManager.h needs to `#include` the file where LogDataRef is defined. Since that would make a circular reference (bad), you need to pull LogDataRef and the other problematic definitions into a separate header, and `#include` it from both AssetMAnager.h and the other header.

Comment: The `typedef` probably need to be part of the class

Comment: @parktomatomi I tried creating another header which contained all the instances and pointers inside, but the errors persisted. Lukas, I tried that as well, but to no avail. I'm currently reading about a singleton class and trying to make every single data managing class be exactly that and have a GetInsance method. Do you think that might be a solution? Also, I want to ask something about class initialization. If the class has been initialized, does the instance stay throughout the runtime of the program, or does it deconstruct as soon as it's not called anywhere?

Comment: A class you declare like this on the stack: `MyClass x;` gets deinitialized when the program goes out of _scope_. If it's inside a function, that's the end of the function. If it's inside an if block, it's the closing brace. If you declare it on the heap: `auto x = new MyClass();`, it won't be deinitialized until you call `delete x;` explicitly. The period between when it's initialized and when it's deleted is called its lifetime. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/   https://arne-mertz.de/2016/01/c-object-lifetimes/

Comment: As for the headers: In C++, declarations (e.g. `struct X { /*... */ };`) need to appear before they're referenced (e.g. `X instance;`). So the common header included by both AssetManager.h and the one with TDGame needs to have the definitions and typedefs for those first four structs _except_ `AssetData`, as well as the associated typedefs except `AssetDataRef`.